# How to Send a Javascript Variable to a Grails Controller to Query Neo4J

Tags: grails, neo4j

I'm a newbie trying to find uses for Neo4J on Grails.

Basically, I've made 20 grocery item nodes through the Neo4J browser and I want to create a simple Grails site that will let users search a grocery item and visually show the items related to it.

My index.gsp has:

```
<input id="item" />
```

My viz.js has:

```
$('#item').keyup(function() {
var item = $('#item').val();
```

My Item Domain class has

```
class Item {
static mapWith = "neo4j"
String name
```

My ItemController class has:

```
def index() {
def item = Item.list() [item:item] //No idea, just trying out whatever i find :(
```

and a query with something like:

```
def query = Item.cypherStatic ("""start n=node({Item}) match (n)-[r]->(x) where r='partner' return n, x)
```

Questions:

1. How can I properly send the JS 'item' variable into the ItemController?
2. How can I use the 'item' variable to properly query the node names which have a 'partner' relationship with the item?

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Motilals answers, you definetly need a wrapping form with an action that points your controller

like

```
 <g:form controller="itemController" action="index" >

     <input type="text" id="item" name="item" value="" /> 
     <input type="submit" value="submit" >
 </g:form>
```

then on clicking submit the for will call your index action and there you could parse the value with

```
 def item = params.item
```

but it looks more like you want some asynchronous stuff right after keyup-function, therefore you could do sth like this :

```
 $('#item').keyup(function() {
    var item = $('#item').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "${createLink(controller:'itemController', action:'index')}",
      data:"&item="+item
      })
    .done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data)
    });
 });
```

in this case, you need to pay attention what your index-action is returning, so you can do in the .done() whatever you want with the response.

also note, that when you name an action "index" it will be available at

```
 .../myproject/item/index
```

or, and thats important

```
.../myproject/item/
```

so if your index method requires the data from the input, it will miss them if a user has gone straight to that url

so your index action would rather render the page with the input
and you define another action for executing your query based on input and returning data

Comment: Thanks, I put it in a form, but avoided the asynchronous stuff because it's a bit intimidating. I was able to get the variable into the def item, but I'm still stuck with how to send it to the Neo4J cypher query.

Comment: try to replace "({Item})" with "(${item})"

Answer (score 0):

set the item to hidden field and then you can access it directly in your controller using params

here you go:

```
 //in index.gsp add below hidden field and set the hidden filed in your js code
    <g:hiddenField name="item" value="" /> 

    $('#item').keyup(function() {
    var item = $('#item').val();

    //in your controller
    def index() {
     def item = params.item
     print item // you see the value for item
     //do your stuff
    }
```

once you have item value you could directly use HQL query or use the domain instance

hope this helps you

Regards
Motilal

Comment: Is the hidden field a requirement to access the variable? I found a similar issue that didn't need hidden field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020519/how-to-get-the-input-from-a-text-box-on-a-webpage-form

Comment: Yes, Hidden field is required: in your code you are not assigning the value to the text filed directly.